# Access mockserver from postman

Tags: docker, postman, mockserver

I would like to set a mock server using https://mock-server.com/.
As postman limits the numbers of calls with its free version I have opted for this tool.
I have pulled and run the mock server docker image here is what I have when launching docker ps :

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                                          COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NAMES
b972ce4db023   mockserver/mockserver                                                          "java -Dfile.encodinÔÇª"   6 seconds ago   Up 4 seconds   0.0.0.0:49153->1080/tcp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          jovial_kala
```

My question is how can I make a call to this mock server now from postman?

Comment: you can have 1000 calls per month in postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postman supports 1000 calls per month with its free license ,

coming back to your question expose the container in any hostport and use it like any
https://localhost:port/endpoint

https://mock-server.com/where/docker.html

to expose to hostport use:

```
   docker run -d --rm -p <theport you want to use>:1080 mockserver/mockserver
```

eg:
docker run -d --rm -p 9999:1080 mockserver/mockserver

and the service will be now available at localhost:9999

Comment: Correct regarding the port binding. Unnecessary to tell OP what they already know as they said "postman limits the numbers of calls with its free version."

Comment: @im_baby The answer is not just for the OPs its for the community , some might mis- interpret postman documentation to think 1000 calls all together after that we should move to paid version. But its actually 1000 calls per month, hope its clear :) https://www.postman.com/pricing/

Comment: https://{usome-user}-public.postman.co/billing/add-ons/overview , this shows the usage and it shows n/1000 doesn't mention it renews every month

Comment: I am curious to know if it's per months or not as if it's 1000 calls per month it should be sufficient for my use.

Comment: @ziwdig44bugs it is :)  see the pricing list and scroll down  : https://www.postman.com/pricing/